# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘webdriver_manager.Edge

Tags: python, selenium

I’m getting the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘webdriver_manager.Edge’. My Code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.Edge import ChromeDriverManager

def Mok():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver=webdriver.Edge(options=chrome_options, service=Service(EdgeDriverManager().install()))
    start_url='netlify.com'
    driver.get(start_url)
    print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
    driver.get_screenshot_as_png('reddit.png')
    print(driver.title)
    driver.close()
Mok()
```

Comment: I believe the correct import statement is `from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import 
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

[...]

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a typo in your code:

See https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#use-with-edge

If you are using `webdriver_manager` as your package.

Use with Edge:

```
# selenium 3
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())

# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, we need to install or we need to have access the module before importing it if the module is user-defined.

The error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'" also implies that we didn't install the **webdriver-manager** module or we are importing it or installing it in an incorrect environment. To fix this error, install the module in the appropriate working directory or in a virtual environment by running the command.

`pip install webdriver-manager`